# How do correlate symbol information from PDB with PE contents?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, symbols, virtual-address-space

I've been trying to get a better understanding of where my C++ source code ends up in a PE format and how to find specific points in my source code in the PE.  For example, I have a [simple program](https://github.com/jokem59/Technotes/tree/master/Debuggers) which I've compiled with /Od and /ZI flags.

There's one source file with the following functions: `main`, `PrintVector`, `AddOneToEach`.

When I open `main.exe` in a hex editor, I can correlate addresses and values in the PE image with certain values from `dumpbin ./main.exe /headers` using [PE structure documentation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg) as a reference.  For example:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               7 number of sections
        5E48E9D4 time date stamp Sat Feb 15 23:05:56 2020
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           14.16 linker version
           9DA00 size of code
           25400 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
           4BD1C entry point (0044BD1C) @ILT+19735(_mainCRTStartup)
```

I know that at address 0x3c, I should find a 4-byte long field that contains the address of the start of the PE Header.  I find in little endian format `0x00010000` which translates to `0x00000100`.  At address `0x00000100`, I find the expected little endian value of `0x50450000` per the [PE format documentation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg).

When examining the associated PDB file, I look up the symbol `PrintVector` via powershell `& $dbh ./main.pdb n PrintVector` where `$dbh = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbh.exe`.    The ouput is:

```
   name : PrintVector
   addr :  1059090
   size : 86
  flags : 0
   type : 2
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagExe (1)
    tag : SymTagFunction (5)
  index : 1
```

Given the address value of `0x01059090`, my expectation is to be able to find the start of the function `PrintVector` at address `0x01059090` in main.exe.  However, the address range main.exe ends at `0x000cf15f0`, which tells my there's something wrong with my understanding of Virtual Addressing and the PE format.  My expectation is that I should be able to find the entry point into the function `PrintVector` somewhere in main.exe based on the address pulled via Dumpbin using DBH on the PDB file.  Where is my understanding breaking down?

Comment: `1059090 - 1000000 == 59090`. so *rva* of `PrintVector` is `59090`. add this *rva* to actual base address, at which *exe* file mapped at runtime and you got address of `PrintVector`

Comment: I see that `0x00059090` is within main.exe's address space, however, when I examine that address, all I see are the values `0xcccccccc` for the first 84-bytes, then in little endian, `0x8bff` for the last 2-bytes for the total size of 86-bytes as reported by dbh.  However, when running dbh on the symbol `AddOneToEach`, it points me to `0x01059092 - 0x01000000 == 0x00059092` and I see some reasonable values for bytes there.

Comment: Also, when using dbh, I see that the addr of `name addonetoeach` is `0x01059020` and it's size is `54` which I'm assuming is in bytes.  The `next addonetoeach` reveals that `PrintVector` is the next symbol, but it's address is > 54 bytes from the address of `AddOneToEach` and I'm unsure as to why.